# The best way to perform time gap analysis with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm trying to find the best way to approach a simple time gap analysis with Python and Pandas. This is just for fun, so feel free to explain answers to help me learn more.

I started off by generating some random data. First is dates with a time stamp frequency of 20 seconds over the total periods for 4 sessions across 2 users. The users are 123 and 345.

The simulation here is a snapshot every 20 seconds to see if the user is online or not.

```
import pandas as pd

session_one = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=100, freq='20S')
session_two = pd.date_range('2016-02-01', periods=75, freq='20S')
session_three = pd.date_range('2016-01-01', periods=125, freq='20S')
session_four = pd.date_range('2016-02-01', periods=25, freq='20S')

user_one = [session_one, session_two]
user_two = [session_three, session_four]

data = []

for sessions in user_one:
    for dates in sessions:
        data.append([123,dates])

for sessions in user_two:
    for dates in sessions:
        data.append([345,dates])

# Make our dataframe with our randomly generated data
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['ID', 'Timestamp'])
```

**Trying To Achieve**

I want to measure the time gap between each user record and append it back on the record.

**SQL Approach**

I have a good SQL approach, but can't seem to replicate joining datasets ontop of each other and offsetting the times correctly with Pandas. For example, doing a Pandas merge (join) like such:

```
df['Timestamp'] + datetime.timedelta(0,20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by each `UserID` with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('UserID')['Timestamp'].diff()
```

Comment: How easy that was jesus. *bonk*

Comment: I was not sure, because question seems more complicated. Good luck!

Comment: Yeah, didn't think .diff() would iterate over the next record to show the time difference versus having to pivot the time to do something like DATEDIFF(SECONDS,field1, field2) like in SQL.

Comment: Nope, answer is right. Just waiting for Stack to let me check it. :)

Comment: @jezrael How would this solution change if we were working with a Series object instead of a Dataframe where "Timestamp" would be the index, i.e.: `pd.Series(df['UserID'].values,index=pd.to_datetime(df['date']))`

Comment: I think you need df because create new column, so use `df=df.reset_index()` and `df['diff'] = df.groupby('UserID')['index'].diff()` if dates are in column called index.

Comment: But if need output new series then use `s1 = s.index.to_series().groupby(s).diff()`